# Knockout Observable Array not binding future element in html

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, knockout.js

i have created a simple table with knockout observable array,and on button click  there is an another table with selected items.
but observable array change not binding html view.
here is my code in fiddle

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    ViewModel  = function(){
        var self = this;
        self.plant = [
            {name:"plant 1",selected:true},{name:"palnt 2",selected:false},{name:"plant 3",selected:true},{name:"plant 4",selected:false}
        ];
        self.PlantSelected = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.gridSelectedSave  = function(obj){
            console.log(obj);
            this.temp = [];
            self.PlantSelected = ko.observableArray([]);
            if(obj.length > 0){
                for(var i = 0;i<obj.length;i++){
                    if(obj[i].selected){                        
                       this.temp.push(obj[i]);
                    }
                }
            }    

            self.PlantSelected = ko.observableArray(this.temp);
            console.log(self.PlantSelected());
        };
    };
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: plant">
                            <tr>   
                                <td>
                                    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
    </table>
    <hr/>
    <table>
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: PlantSelected">
                            <tr>   
                                <td>
                                    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br/><hr/>
    <div data-bind="click: function(){
         $root.gridSelectedSave(plant);
    }">click to show selected</div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/63ygsd52/

i have spent around one day to fix but not working ,please keep in mind that am a newbie to knockout js. greatly appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot simply overwrite the `PlantSelected` variable, you need to keep the original reference. So instead of `self.PlantSelected = ko.observableArray([]);` you'll need to `self.PlantSelected.removeAll()` and then push the "selected" items directly into it: `self.PlantSelected.push(obj[i]);`.

```
self.gridSelectedSave  = function(obj){
    self.PlantSelected.removeAll()
    if(obj.length > 0){
        for(var i = 0;i<obj.length;i++){
            if(obj[i].selected){                        
               self.PlantSelected.push(obj[i]);
            }
        }
    }    
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1no4oumf/

Answer (score 0):

You can use push method in observable array.

```
self.PlantSelected.push(obj[i]);
```

fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/63ygsd52/1/